# I dont understand this sentence

Tags: understanding

> "The programmes of study will apply from five years of age, likewise the **attainment targets**."

Not much else to add really, specifically the last part I have trouble understanding? How can an attainment target something? I have never seen this constellation, help please.

Comment: "attainment target" is a noun. It's some buzzword specific to the context.

Comment: Does it help to equate "likewise the attainment targets" with "the attainment targets will also apply from five years of age"?

Answer (score 1):

> [attainment targets](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/attainment-target)

are predetermined milestones in the development of a child which need to be achieved for further advancement and continued school certification.  It is a BrE phrase.